# Drawing text through bge module - Drawing several words

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

The code of my script:

```
import drawtext
drawtext.chain = 'Hello World!'
drawtext.positionx = 0
drawtext.positiony = 0
```

The code of the file drawtext.py:

```
# import game engine modules
from bge import render, logic
# import stand alone modules
import bgl, blf

# create a new font object, use external ttf file
font_path = logic.expandPath('C://Documents and Settings//Guillermo//Mis documentos//Google Drive//Gproyectos//Proyectos con Blender//arial.ttf')
# store the font indice - to use later
font_id = blf.load(font_path)
chain = 'this is the message'
positionx = 0.5
positiony = 0.5

def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = render.getWindowWidth()
    height = render.getWindowHeight()
    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    blf.position(font_id, (width * positionx), (height * positiony), 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
    bgl.glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    blf.draw(font_id,chain)

def update(cont):
    own = cont.owner
    chain = own['msg']

# set the font drawing routine to run every frame
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
scene.post_draw = [write]
```

when you run the game engine, you see this:
[image]

And what I want to do is to obtein this:
[image]

How can I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Managing multiple text fragments

I suggest to place the text attributes into a container such such as a class:

```
class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color, font_id):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.font_id = font_id
```

You can use a list or dict too, but I think this is easier to understand as you see the structure of the data.

Then place modify your code that it can work with the above text container:

```
blf.position(text.font_id, (width * text.x), (height * text.y), 0)
blf.size(text.font_id, 50, 72)
bgl.glColor4f(*text.color)
blf.draw(text.font_id, text.text)
```

This still allows just one text to be drawn (as there is just one text container). But now it is pretty easy for us to create a container that can contain any number of texts:

```
texts = []
```

You create that once in your drawtext.py replacing *font_id*, *chain*, *positionx*, *positiony*.

Make sure your write() can deal with more than one text container:

```
for text in texts:
    blf.position(text.font_id, (width * text.x), (height * text.y), 0)
    blf.size(text.font_id, 50, 72)
    bgl.glColor4f(*text.color)
    blf.draw(text.font_id, text.text)
```

Now you can add some comfort to your module, by providing a function that let you easily add new texts:

```
def add(text, x, y, color, font_id=0):
    texts.append(Text(text, x, y, color, font_id))
```

Your using script can look like that:

```
import drawtext
import bge

COLOR_GREEN = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0

if all(sensor.positive for sensor in bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors):
    drawtext.add("Hello Green World!", 0, 0.15, COLOR_GREEN)
```

The complete drawwtext.py can look like that:

```
import bge
import bgl, blf

texts = []           

class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color, font_id):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.font_id = font_id

def add(text, x, y, color, font_id=0):
    return texts.append(Text(text, x, y, color, font_id))

def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = bge.render.getWindowWidth()
    height = bge.render.getWindowHeight()
    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    for text in texts:
        blf.position(text.font_id, (width * text.x), (height * text.y), 0)
        blf.size(text.font_id, 50, 72)
        bgl.glColor4f(*text.color)
        blf.draw(text.font_id, text.text)

bge.logic.getCurrentScene().post_draw = [write]
```

## Font Management

You might have noticed that I skipped fonts in the above code by making them optional. I recommend to manage them separately. The blf-module is the font container already. But you need a way to provide easy access to the loaded fonts without dealing with cryptic numbers. I suggest to create a new module fonts.py encapsulating the load operation:

```
import blf

def load(file):
    return blf.load(bge.logic.expandPath(file))
```

this enables you to declare font "constants" right at the beginning of drawtext.py:

```
FONT_ID_ARIAL = fonts.load("//arial.ttf")
FONT_ID_AGENCYR = fonts.load("//AGENCYR.TTF")
```

Which on the other hand enables you to use them when defining your text fragments:

```
import drawtext
import bge

COLOR_GREEN = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0

if all(sensor.positive for sensor in bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors):
    drawtext.add("Hello Green World!", 0, 0.15, COLOR_GREEN, drawtext.FONT_ID_AGENCYR)
```

The reason why load() is placed in a new module is simply to avoid defining this function before you define the constants, which let the constants be a the pretty top of drawtext.py

## Color Management

You can do a similar method with colors. Right now each user script adds his own color. You can provide a few color constants right at the beginning of the module:

```
COLOR_GREEN = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_RED = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_BLUE = 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
COLOR_BLACK = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_WHITE = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
```

this allows to use them wherever this module is used:

```
import drawtext
import bge

if all(sensor.positive for sensor in bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors):
    drawtext.add("Hello Green World!", 0, 0.15, drawtext.COLOR_GREEN, drawtext.FONT_ID_AGENCYR)
```

## Complete Code

**fonts.py**

```
import bge
import blf

def load(file):
    return blf.load(bge.logic.expandPath(file))
```

**drawtext.py**

```
import bge
import bgl, blf
import fonts

FONT_ID_ARIAL = fonts.load("//arial.ttf")
FONT_ID_AGENCYR = fonts.load("//AGENCYR.TTF")

COLOR_GREEN = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_RED = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_BLUE = 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
COLOR_BLACK = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
COLOR_WHITE = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0

texts = []           

class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color, font_id):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.font_id = font_id

def add(text, x, y, color, font_id=0):
    return texts.append(Text(text, x, y, color, font_id))

def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = bge.render.getWindowWidth()
    height = bge.render.getWindowHeight()
    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    for text in texts:
        blf.position(text.font_id, (width * text.x), (height * text.y), 0)
        blf.size(text.font_id, 50, 72)
        bgl.glColor4f(*text.color)
        blf.draw(text.font_id, text.text)

bge.logic.getCurrentScene().post_draw = [write]
```

**Show Green Text**

```
import drawtext
import bge

if all(sensor.positive for sensor in bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors):
    drawtext.add("Hello Green World!", 0, 0.15, drawtext.COLOR_GREEN, drawtext.FONT_ID_AGENCYR)
```

**Show Red Text**

```
import drawtext

    if all(sensor.positive for sensor in bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors):
    drawtext.add("Hello Red World!",0,0, drawtext.COLOR_RED)
```

## Excercise

I suggest to allow customizing the size of the text fragment. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code of the script:

```
import module_drawseveralwordsII
```

The code of the module_drawseveralwordsII.py:

```
# import game engine modules
from bge import render, logic
# import stand alone modules
import bgl, blf

# create a new font object, use external ttf file
font_path = logic.expandPath('C://Documents and Settings//Guillermo//Mis documentos//Google Drive//Gproyectos//Proyectos con Blender//arial.ttf')
# store the font indice - to use later
font_id = blf.load(font_path)
chain = ["Hello World!","Hello Country!","Hello Town!", "Hello Home!"]
positionx = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6]
positiony = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6]
ccolor1 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
ccolor2 = [0.0,0.0,0.6,0.5]
ccolor3 = [0.0,0.3,0.0,0.5]
ccolor4 = [1.0,1,1,1]

def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = render.getWindowWidth()
    height = render.getWindowHeight()
    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    i = 0
    while i<len(chain):
        blf.position(font_id, (width * positionx[i]), (height * positiony[i]), 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
        bgl.glColor4f(ccolor1[i], ccolor2[i], ccolor3[i], ccolor4[i])
        blf.draw(font_id,chain[i])
        i = i + 1




def update(cont):
    own = cont.owner
    chain = own['msg']

# set the font drawing routine to run every frame
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
scene.post_draw = [write]
```

The differences from the original code are the variable declarations:

```
chain = ["Hello World!","Hello Country!","Hello Town!", "Hello Home!"]
positionx = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6]
positiony = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6]
ccolor1 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
ccolor2 = [0.0,0.0,0.6,0.5]
ccolor3 = [0.0,0.3,0.0,0.5]
ccolor4 = [1.0,1,1,1]
```

And this:

```
  i = 0
    while i<len(chain):
        blf.position(font_id, (width * positionx[i]), (height * positiony[i]), 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
        bgl.glColor4f(ccolor1[i], ccolor2[i], ccolor3[i], ccolor4[i])
        blf.draw(font_id,chain[i])
        i = i + 1
```

This is what we can see:
[image]

I don´t know the exact values of  red, and yellow for the 4f color system. But these values must be available on the web.

Comment: The parameters for glcolor4f correspond to red,green.blue,alpha - yellow is a mix of red and green so 1,1,0,1.